# Loading a CLOB over 32mb using an external table

Tags: oracle, clob, external-tables

I have an external table whose definition looks like this:

```
-- Create table
create table EXT_EXTRACT_XMLS
(
  extract_type  VARCHAR2(100),
  clob_filename VARCHAR2(100),
  xml_clob      CLOB
)
organization external
(
  type ORACLE_LOADER
  default directory MY_DIRECTORY
  access parameters 
  (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    BADFILE MY_DIRECTORY:'Xml_Extract.bad'
    LOGFILE MY_DIRECTORY:'Xml_Extract.log'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
    (
      extract_type  char(100),
      clob_filename char(100)
    )
    COLUMN TRANSFORMS (xml_clob FROM LOBFILE (clob_filename))
  )
  location (MY_DIRECTORY:'xml_extract_list.txt')
)
reject limit UNLIMITED;
```

Within the directory MY_DIRECTORY, I have a file named xml_extract_list.txt that looks like this:

```
A,extractA.xml
```

Within the same directory, I have a file extractA.xml which I am trying to load into the table, as a single row with the CLOB column in that row containing the XML.

This is mostly working fine as long as the XML file is under 32mb. Once the file is over 32mb, this starts erroring and I can no longer read the CLOBs.

Is this a limitation of external tables, or is there an option or parameter that I can change to load a file over 32mb as a CLOB?

**More Information**

The error message that I select from the table is:

[image: selecting from table]

Since the column is a CLOB, I cannot use the DUMP function to investigate what is happening behind the scenes.

The logfile generated by the external table is not giving any error message.

The badfile generated by the external table is empty.

When attempting to query it using sqlplus, it looks a bit malformed:
[image]

Comment: well what is the error?

Comment: @OldProgrammer more information added

Comment: That looks like an issue in your client when it tries to display the value, rather than with the value or the external table. Is this PL/SQL Developer, and if so which version? What happens when you run the same query in another client, like SQL Developer or SQL/*Plus?

Comment: @AlexPoole I've added a screenshot of when it looks like in sqlplus.
I don't think it's a client issue, as I can query other CLOBs over 32mb without issue.

Comment: Have you checked the file to make sure it doesn't just have garbage or control characters at the start? Is it the right character set?

Answer (score 0):

Try

https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/external-tables-containing-lob-data

```
create table lob_tab (
  id            number,
  clob_content  clob
)
organization external
(
  type oracle_loader
  default directory temp_dir
  access parameters
  (
    records delimited by newline
    badfile temp_dir:'lob_tab_%a_%p.bad'
    logfile temp_dir:'lob_tab_%a_%p.log'
    fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
    missing field values are null
    (
      id,
      clob_content  char(1000000) 
    )
  )
  location ('inline_clob_test1.txt')
)
parallel 2
reject limit unlimited;
```